# ProcessBar во время генерации файла в asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, firefox

Появился вопрос по поводу как сделать processbar во время генерации файла.
Пробовал так:

```js
     $("#download-button").click(function () {

        var req = getXHR();

        req.open('GET', '/Home/DownloadImage', true);
        req.onreadystatechange = function (aEvt) {

            if (req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {

                $('#progressMsg').hide();
            }
        };
        $('#progressMsg').show();
        req.send(null);
    });
```

В `Chrome` и `IE` все работает отлично, но не работает в `FireFox`.

Конкретнее: все время выводит, что `req.status = 0`; в то время, как в `Chrome` = 200;

Comment: @PavelMayorov извиняюсь, плохо скопировал. Уже исправил.

Comment: Вы сами не замечаете, что ваш вопрос - про javascript, а не про asp.net mvc?

Comment: По сути вопроса же - вы явно стерли что-то лишнее. Приведенный код выглядит рабочим...

Comment: @PavelMayorov в Хроме - да, работает. в ФайрФоксе же мой прогрессбар не исчезает (.hide()). Так как он не входит в условие IF(так как почему-то, req.status == 0).

Comment: @PavelMayorov интересно то, что когда изменяю значение "async" на false - возвращает state 200, таким как и должен.