# Индикатор процесса в веб приложении

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Пытаюсь сделать `индикатор процесса` в веб приложении (некий `progressbar`).

Во время того, как в `Controller` идет генерация файла, я хочу, что бы пользователь видел, что идет генерация и он понимал, что приложение работает. 
Сделать его хочу максимально простым. Просто что бы была надпись или .gif c крутящимся колесиком. После того, как файл выгенерирован, начинается его загрузка, и перед загрузкой надо убрать этот индикатор.

**Пытался** я сделать [вот так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/566562/processbar-%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B2-asp-net-mvc), но ничего **не получилось**.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какие еще варианты реализации еще могут быть ?

*За **примеры** и **туториалы** - отдельное **спасибо**.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете использовать Ajax.BeginForm ([Примитивный пример тут](http://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/10.3.php)), если возможно частичное обновление страницы без полной перезагрузки. LoadingElementId как раз отвечает за автоматическое отображение индикатора на протяжении выполнения метода. Достаточно только создать div с элементом анимации, а скрытие и отображение осуществляются автоматически.

Заодно посмотрите назначение других параметров. Например, OnComplete позволяет вызвать выполнение какой-либо js-функции после выполнения запроса. UpdateTargetId позволяет указать область, которая будет обновляться, заменяя прежнее содержимое тем представлением, которое вернётся контроллером. Привожу минимальный кусочек кода из своего проекта, надеюсь, что будет понятно.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "Get",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    UpdateTargetId = "target",
    LoadingElementId = "loader"
}))
{
    /* Область, которая будет получать обновления */
    <div id="target">
        @Html.Partial("_Index")
    </div>

    /* Элемент-анимация загрузки */
    <div id="loader" style="display:none">
        <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/loading.gif")" alt="" />
        Ваш запрос выполняется...
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Cпасибо огромное за помощь ! Сделал по Вашему примеру, но почему-то не работает =(

Comment: @kxxko я много всего повыкидывала из кода, оставила только каркас, так что вполне может быть, что что-то нужное для понимания упустила. Я, конечно, не гуру asp.net, но давайте попробуем разобраться тогда :) Что именно не работает?

Comment: объясните мне, пожалуйста, зачем мне тут нужен "target" =)

Comment: Я немного переделал - заработало. Начал появляться Loader, но перестал скачиваться файл )